# Angular/CLI *ngIf causing performance issues with I.E

Tags: angular, performance, internet-explorer, responsive-design

So in my code, I do something similar to below, and I do this a lot.  I design my site to be responsive, and yes, the result of the conditions do change, depending on user interaction.  I might have as many as 20 or 30 of these on a single page, after all, the whole point is to be SPA. The page opens and closes sections based on selections by a user.

When I run my App in Chrome, it works fine.  But when I run it in I.E. it's virtually unresponsive, the blue wheel just spins.  I hate I.E. as much as the next developer, but telling me I.E. sucks is not an acceptable response.  I do not have the luxury of telling I.E. users not to use my site.

Question: Is there a way to do this better, to still be responsive, yet, work in I.E.?  I was binding to `[hidden]` instead of `*ngIf`, but I read that `*ngIf` is more efficient.  I was using <div> instead of <template> but read that <template>  is more efficient.

```
<template *ngIf="some condition">
      responsive html section here
</template>
```

Yes, I realize I.E. is obsolete.  Yet again, that makes no difference, I need to support I.E. users for this app.

Comment: what is the `some condition`? variable or function? you do not want to have function there.

Comment: Which version of IE are you targeting? And which version of Angular?

Comment: This could be *any number* of things with IE unfortunately....because, like you said, IE is...well, you know. One thing you could try is `ngSwitch` insteach of `*ngIf`, depending on your needs. Could also be animations. Check my answer to a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43986588/angular-2-how-to-improve-dom-painting-time-on-internet-explorer-11/43988511#43988511

Comment: @PEs The 'some condition' actually is a function in some cases, in some cases, nothing but a variable.  So I take it you are saying 'never a function'?

Comment: @Joel Brewer As for 'version of IE', I'm not really 'targeting' a version, but I need to be able to support IE 11 for sure.
As for Angular, I am using Angular 7

Comment: @joh04667 As for animations, I don't use any animations, but I will read your other answer.

Comment: @joh04667, your comments on ChangeDetectorRef might be huge for me.  It will take me a bit to get this all figured out, but I really appreciate that, that might be the smoking gun.